# how to solve cross domain issue with 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, cross-domain

Work on WCF service,Have two domain,they are respectively **http://hello** and **http://world** .My service deployed in **world** domain server.Access service from world work **perfectly** ,

Project special purpose  need to access service from **hello** domain,for that reason I forward domain **hello** to **world**,it’s work **perfectly**. But problem arise when I try to access service from hello show me bellow error

**HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed**

It may be **cross** domain issue I try to follow [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/wcf/X8QN260412-Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-Service-using-Jquery.html) one but problem remains what to do?

**Note:** for service test used fiddler.